# Converting to open stringer stairs with starting newel location contrained

Tags: stairs, renovation, handrail

We just recently purchased a new house that we are doing major renovation work to. One of the big changes we are making is converting the staircase from a closed drywall rail to an open tread style rail. I am working through a lot of issues with getting the stairs laid out to current codes, but one of the bigger issues I am not sure how to get around is the "starting newel" on the stair. It is really a column supporting an overhanging slab above. I do plan to move the column plan north to align with the corner of the overhang (to the left in the picture below) but I am constrained in the plan X direction since it is already flush with the overhang.

[image: Looking at the stair]

The edge of drywall wall to edge of drywall column is currently ~40". I planned to pull off the drywall and wrap the 2x4s with decorative wood to simulate a newel post running to the overhang support. The drywall below the stairs in locked in place as well because it is the shared wall for the basement steps, because I don't want to/can't make them narrower than 36".

Adding a 3/4" stringer on the drywall puts me at 40-3/4" inches. Everything I have read for open tread stairs say that handrails should be aligned to 1/2 baluster diameter from the skirt (Ironically it is also how I have done it on previous builds without even knowing just because it looked good to me!). Assuming that newel posts should be centered with the handrail, with a 1-1/4" baluster, that puts the center line at 40-1/8". The center line of the column is 3' 1-5/8", so 2-1/2" INSIDE the normal center line. Kind of the opposite of every starting newel I have seen.

I was really hoping to have the newels sit proud of the skirt board, or at least the landing newels like the image below. Without moving the walls and trying to align to this column, I don't see an option to do this. Am I missing something?

[image: Newel Proud of Skirt]

Other than having a large amount of tread outside the balusters, my only thought was to mimic a 5-1/5" starting newel and continue with 3" landing newels and align the outside edges and center the railing on that. I haven't been able to find any images on that though. Obviously structurally the column has to stay there, but is there a way to aesthetically pull that column out a couple inches without making it look silly?

I drafted up the locations of everything and took a couple snapshots of what I am working with. Hopefully the images below are helpful. I am not really sure what my options are here. Any thoughts or ideas are welcome!

[image: Stair Overall]

[image: Close Up]

Comment: That's a lot of text & pics (which is good!), but I think it all boils down to, "Obviously structurally the column has to stay there, but is there a way to _aesthetically_ pull that column out a couple inches without making it look silly?" (emphasis added). Aesthetics are very opinion-based which makes this, unfortunately, off-topic, because what I think looks good probably won't be what you think looks good.

Comment: I figured more information was better than people asking me a bunch of questions trying to understand the initial post!  Agreed, trying to move the column visually is aesthetical. Honestly if there it a way to move it structurally and still support the floor above, I am all ears too. I am also open to any other suggestions to make this stair functional with the wall stuck where it is and a 3-1/2"x3-1/2" column stuck where it is.